# Empty form values are not included in params in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Resource form contents:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do      
    f.input :name
  end

  f.actions
end
```

I am using Rails 5 beta 3, here is `Gemfile` contents:

```
# Backend
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin/activeadmin', branch: 'master'
```

`Gemfile.lock` contents:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git
  revision: f7483e3b8fcd74437b03c18fb658dac62a9fc62e
  branch: master
  specs:
    activeadmin (1.0.0.pre2)
      arbre (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      bourbon
      coffee-rails
      formtastic (~> 3.1)
      formtastic_i18n
      inherited_resources (~> 1.6)
      jquery-rails
      jquery-ui-rails
      kaminari (~> 0.15)
      rails (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
      ransack (~> 1.3)
      sass-rails
      sprockets (< 4)
```

Even attribute is included in permitted params:

```
permit_params :name
```

it's missing in `params` when I submit empty value and as a result name is not updated. Non-empty values work OK.

Same with select boxes.

After error occured, I tried to update Active Admin with:

```
bundle update activeadmin
```

but error still remains.

I tested it on simple rails form (generated by scaffold command) and formtastic outside of Active Admin resource, both options work, so it seems to be Active Admin problem.

Here is how I checked `params` content (also checked `logs/development.log`):

```
controller do
  def update
    abort params.inspect
  end
end
```

So `name` is not presented even at this moment.

I posted issue [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4327) but no feedback till now.

Comment: Did you intently left f.actions in your form?

Comment: @AlifJamaluddin Yes, `f.actions` part is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using rails5.0.0beta2, you are probably also using rack 2.0.0.alpha.

This is caused by a [bug in rack](https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/1009).

Until rack2.0.0 become stable, you can solve this bug by adding to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack', github: 'rack/rack'
```